# Push Notifications at a specific time

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way i can set a notification to show up at a specific time? Like every day at 10:00 am Saying To Open The App And Read Whats in the app? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

That's not a push notification, it's a local notification. (And yes, you can.)

Answer (score -2):

The question you have asked can be achieved through local notifications using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger

The explanations are provided in following link

http://irekasoft.com/blog/usernotifications-framework-example